# How to change the names of files to integers, so that files that were created later are named with larger numbers?

Tags: python, sorting, integer, file-rename, creation

I made myself a script, which downloads pictures every 2 seconds and puts them into a folder. Now I want the first picture I downloaded to be named "1", the second "2", etc. It can start at "0". That's not really important. I guess the mistake lies in `getctime`, because the sorting somehow messes up.

Since I sort the files, `os.listdir` random order shouldn't matter. I don't think I messed up the `lambda` function, but currently I'm at a loss. I tried using `getmtime`, but it doesn't work either.

The programs results is this:

[image]

The numbers assigned are in a seemingly random order.
Ctime should not change before saving it in file_data_list.
Count+extension might throw an error, but is easily fixed.
I tried to run this on 450 pictures downloaded over 13 minutes with 2 seconds in between each picture, so the resolution of the ctime attribute should not be a problem.

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir('./')
# get the list of all files in the directory and sort them after creation time
file_date_list = sorted(filelist, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x))

# go through the sorted list and rename them
for count,file in enumerate(file_date_list):
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    os.rename(file, count+extension)
input()
```

Comment: Did this raise an error (e.g., `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`)? What was messed up in the result?

Comment: The result was, that the files were not sorted after the ctime. I compacted the code for posting it here. Originally i concatenated two strings and not  a string and an int. Here is the result: https://i.imgur.com/duMBDa1.png The second column is date in ascending order.

Comment: Its possible for multiple files to have the same ctime making their relative position in that time frame arbitrary. A quick test on my system showed a time change at about 4 mS.

Comment: But did they get sequentially increasing numbers based on original ctime? In linux/mac, rename changes ctime, which seems to have happened here. And a future directory listing will be arbitrary, except maybe the list will be alphabetically sorted by the utility. Your utility could also sort by ctime, but that changed in the rename.

Comment: That is what i wonderer as well. I thought, i was realtivel save, since i spaced the downloads out with 2 seconds in between. I do not know, if the time written to the ctime attribute of the file is the time i actually downloaded it. It might be problematic if the download took too long. I downloaded around 450 pictures in a total of 13 minutes. So the first file i downloaded shouldn't be the 118. I checked a lot of the pictures, and the way windows explorer sorts it, is correct.

Comment: I guess the ctime chaning after a rename could be an issue, but shouldn't be here. Since i grab all the ctime information and save the files in rising order in file_data_list, changing ctime after the creation of file_data_list shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indicate **in it** _how_ it's not working and include the full backtrace.

Comment: you could create correct filename when you save downloaded file - not later. And you could  use name with `year-month-day-hours-minutes-seconds` because it can be correctly sorted by name. ie. `image_2020-06-16_03-04-56.jpg`

Comment: BTW: if you use numbers in filename then better use `"001"` instead of `"1"` because when you will sort by name then strings `"10"`, `"11"` ... `"19"` are before `"2:` - but `"002"` is before `"010"`

Comment: I could change the name immediatly when downloading. That was what i first thought about. Sadly i don't have a clue yet on how to crawl websites properly and get all the image files. Currently i just have a scirpt that simulates keystrokes and i go do something else, while it downloads. Of course having it just run in the background would be the prefered solution, but i don't know how to do that. Regarding the number names. I agree with you, that formatting them like you suggest is better, but i want to join all the pngs to a pdf, and this step isnt affected by either of the 2 formattings.

Comment: @martineua: The code is running to completion, but the screenshot shows the file name numbering does not order of the timestamps shown.

Comment: Side-issue: `file` is a predefined identifier that gets hidden when you reuse it as an identifier here. Don't use file as a variable.`file_` is one workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help:

```
for count,file in enumerate(file_date_list):
    filename, extension = file.split('.',1)
    os.rename(file, f"{count}.{extension}")
```

Comment: No it didnt. I added the "." back since it got removed by the split, but the outcome is the same

Comment: That seems to assume that a filename will only have one dot.

Comment: @Oddthinking At least *that* issue is fixed.